# While adding image make width as same as screen while height scrollable

Tags: css, html

I have an image of 2000* 8000 pixels. I wanted to make the width as same as the loading window while the height must be scrollable. 
I mean that after the page loads width:100% and height:25% must only be displayed of the image. Then when i scroll down the rest of the height must be displayed i.e. the image should only scroll downwards not sideways.

```css
.img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: inherit !important;
}

html {
  background: url(importantwebsite.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  /*-webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;*/  
}
```

I have used the above code but it displays 100% width and 25% height, And the rest of the image is not shown. Please help..!!

Comment: you might need a wrapper with an `{overflow-x:hidden;}`artibute to wont let it scroll over the x-axis (horizontally). The reason for the wrapper is that if you apply it to the body tag, mobile devices will ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/uoco335z/

change the `width:100%` and `height:auto` of the image

```css
.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img class="img" src="http://placeimg.com/2000/8000/any">
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `max-height:100%` and apply `height:100% !important` like below.

```
  .img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height:100% !important;
  }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mwdsu097/)